# cannot start docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using docker-machine to setup docker on my remote instance. 
The daemon refuses to start

```
(services)  synon (master) ✗ docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-region=us-west-2 --amazonec2-zone=a --amazonec2-instance-type=c4.xlarge --amazonec2-ami=ami-efd0428f synon
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(synon) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error:
command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
err     : exit status 1
output  : Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

My `sytemctl status docker.service`

```
ubuntu@synon:~$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─10-machine.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-07-03 09:07:57 UTC; 2min 37s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 5352 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver aufs --tlsverify --tls
 Main PID: 5352 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 03 09:07:57 synon systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 03 09:07:57 synon systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 03 09:07:57 synon systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 03 09:07:57 synon systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 03 09:07:57 synon systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 03 09:07:57 synon systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 03 09:07:57 synon systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
lines 1-16/16 (END)Wrapper Docker Machine process exiting due to closed plugin server (unexpected EOF)
```

This is my `journalctl -xe`:

```
ubuntu@synon:~$ journalctl -xe
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 03 09:10:24 synon systemd[5362]: Reached target Default.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 03 09:10:24 synon systemd[5362]: Startup finished in 7ms.
-- Subject: System start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- All system services necessary queued for starting at boot have been
-- successfully started. Note that this does not mean that the machine is
-- now idle as services might still be busy with completing start-up.
-- 
-- Kernel start-up required KERNEL_USEC microseconds.
-- 
-- Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.
-- 
-- Userspace start-up required 7322 microseconds.
Jul 03 09:10:24 synon systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
-- Subject: Unit user@1000.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user@1000.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 03 09:16:25 synon sudo[5414]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls /var/lib/docker
Jul 03 09:16:25 synon sudo[5414]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
Jul 03 09:16:25 synon sudo[5414]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 03 09:17:01 synon CRON[5418]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 03 09:17:01 synon CRON[5419]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 03 09:17:01 synon CRON[5418]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

I don't see anything wrong anywhere, why is my docker engine refusing to start?

Comment: The journal seems to be already past the `docker.service` unit. Can you give the output of `journalctl -xe -u docker.service` instead? Also, what version of Docker Machine and some information about the AMI (`ami-efd0428f`) would be helpful as well.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ? I got same issue.

Comment: i updated my `docker-machine`